# Mod rewrite to redirect except on a certain page

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Trying to write a rewrite rule in my htaccess so that any request to /en/shop/index.html or /fr/shop/index.html stays on the server, but if the user goes to any other page it redirects to a different server.  Here's what I've got so far and it doesn't work.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/shop/(.*) [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newwebsite.com/$1 [R=301]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a dash to tell the first RewriteRule that you want the matches to be passed through unchanged:

`RewriteRule ^.*/shop(/.*)?$ - [L]`

I also removed the first set of parentheses since you're not using the results of the match so there's no need to store the matched patterns. I assumed you might need to match /shop without a trailing slash so that's why the `(/.*)?` section is there.